# Dynamically include files in MSI setup

Tags: windows-installer, installation

I am trying to deploy a bunch of files in a directory in my MSI setup. As the files will change frequently I don't want to add the files directly but rather have a way of automatically including all files from within a directory and deploy them to a certain location.

I am using a Visual Studio Setup Project.

Anybody know how/if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by a workaround:

- Add a build action of packaging entire directory (could be filtered) to a ZIP file.
- Add a reference to an empty ZIP file to deployment project.
- Add a custom action to deployment project to extract the ZIP to destination folder.

It's simple and stable.

Comment: how do you zip and unzip it? is there a command or do you need to ship a zip application?

Comment: The project I worked on, already had reference to ICSharpZipLib under appropriate license, so the C# custom action was really handy in my case.

Comment: does it also uninstall these items when you uninstall the application?

Comment: Sure, during un-installation the whole INSTALLDIR directory with deployed files is been deleted. It was done by other non-related custom action anyway.There is nothing special, because other files like log files are should be deleted too. VS Uninstaller deletes only files deployed by itself nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Using what????

WiX? InstallShield? Visual Studio? WISE? InstallAware? MSI Factory? Some other Windows Installer tool?

- InstallShield - yes. Add a 'dynamic folder' to your setup.
- WiX - kind of. Use `heat` to generate (partial) WiX sources before calling candle/light.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in NSIS by generating part of my NSIS script in Perl and having a master script which included the dynamic script.

Short answer: it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

select the folder path and pass to this method.It will create the msi file in the order in which folder hierarchy exists.

public class InstallData
    {
        public void GetWixData(string SourcePath)
        {
         try
            {
                WixEntity[] weDir = new WixEntity[0];
                weDir = BuildDirInfo(SourcePath, weDir);

```
            var project = new Project("My Product", new Dir("MyDB", weDir), new ManagedAction("MyAction"))
            {
                GUID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                UI = WUI.WixUI_InstallDir,
                Manufacturer = "xxx Inc.",

            };



            try
            {



                Compiler.BuildMsi(project, Application.StartupPath);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }

        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }
    }


    private WixEntity[] BuildDirInfo(string sRootDir, WixEntity[] weDir)
    {
        DirectoryInfo RootDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sRootDir);
        if (RootDirInfo.Exists)
        {
            DirectoryInfo[] DirInfo = RootDirInfo.GetDirectories();
            List<string> lMainDirs = new List<string>();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo DirInfoSub in DirInfo)
                lMainDirs.Add(DirInfoSub.FullName);
            int cnt = lMainDirs.Count;
            weDir = new WixEntity[cnt + 1];
            if (cnt == 0)
                weDir[0] = new DirFiles(RootDirInfo.FullName + @"\*.*");
            else
            {
                weDir[cnt] = new DirFiles(RootDirInfo.FullName + @"\*.*");
                for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo RootSubDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(lMainDirs[i]);
                    if (!RootSubDirInfo.Exists)
                        continue;
                    WixEntity[] weSubDir = new WixEntity[0];
                    weSubDir = BuildDirInfo(RootSubDirInfo.FullName, weSubDir);
                    weDir[i] = new Dir(RootSubDirInfo.Name, weSubDir);
                }
            }
        }


        return weDir;
    }
}
```

public class CustomActions
   {
       [CustomAction]
       public static ActionResult MyAction(Session session)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Hello World!", "Embedded Managed CA");
           session.Log("Begin MyAction Hello World");

```
       return ActionResult.Success;
   }
```

}